# Positive Scenario Usage of StatusReport google home trait

Tags: google-smart-home

In Google documentation, they explained how to use "statusReport" trait for query intent when there is an error or exception  occurred for a device. I'm facing issue while using it for success status without any exception. I tried sending the response with simple status as SUCCESS, Google Home is saying the response "Sorry Unable to reach device".

The response which I was sending:
`{ "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf", "payload": { "devices": { "123": { "online": true, "status": "SUCCESS" } } } }`

can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the full JSON response you're sending? There may be something in your response that is not included, such as `online`.

Comment: I was sending json response as mentioned below `{
  "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
  "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "123": {
        "online": true,
        "status": "SUCCESS"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Oh you're not even returning an empty `currentStatusReport` array?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code, it is clear that you’re not sending the correct & complete response of the StatusReport trait. Your response contains the online attribute but missing the currentStatusReport attribute (it is required as it defines the current error statuses of the associated device IDs). For more information, visit https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/statusreport?hl=en